# Align HTML elements horizontally in a div

Tags: html, css

I have three HTML objects and want to arrange Previous button at the left side, Next button at right side and span in the middle inside a container div.

```
<PREVIOUS> |SPAN| <NEXT>
```

```css
    #btnPrevious
    {
        float:left;
    }
    #spanStage
    {
        font-weight:bold;
        vertical-align:middle;    
    }
    #btnNext
    {
        float:right;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Previous" id="btnPrevious"/>
        <span id="spanStage">Stage 5</span>
        <input type="button" value="Next" id="btnNext"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: have you considered using flexbox? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just add `text-align: center` to your wrapper to set the horizontal alignment of all non-floating/non-positioned children:

```
div{
    text-align:center;
}
```

`<span>` are inline elements by default. Thus you either have to use `display:block` on them and style them appropriately, or just tweak the parent style a little bit. Since there are no other children than the `<span>` and the `<button>`s your best of with this simple solution.

Note that `text-align:<value>` gets inherited from the parent, so if you want to include something else in your wrapper you should check whether `text-align:center` is okay for you. Otherwise use `text-align:<value>` in the specific element, where `value` is `left`, `right`, `center` or `justify`.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BJxKM/1/)

Answer (score 61):

The "display:flex" style is a good way to make these elements in same line. No matter what kind of element in the div. Especially if the input class is form-control,other solutions like bootstrap, inline-block will not work well.

Example:

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center">
     <input type="button" value="Previous" id="btnPrevious"/>
     <span id="spanStage">Stage 5</span>
     <input type="button" value="Next" id="btnNext"/>
</div>
```

More detail about flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

flex-direction: row, column

justify-content: flex-end, center, space-between, space-around

align-items: stretch, flex-start, flex-end, center

Comment: could you please add more abot **flex**  it can help more for people who new to css flex concpets .

Answer (score 14):

Try using `display:flex`.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <input type="button" value="Previous" id="btnPrevious"/>
    <span id="spanStage">Stage 5</span>
    <input type="button" value="Next" id="btnNext"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Add the class `line` to all the children elements that you want in a single line and **voila**! They are **obeying you** to stay in a line.

```css
.line {
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="button" class="line" value="Previous" id="btnPrevious"/>
    <span id="spanStage" class="line">Stage 5</span>
    <input type="button" class="line" value="Next" id="btnNext"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add this to your css.

```
#btnPrevious,#spanStage,#btnNext {
      width:33%;
       display:inline-block;
     }
```