# Center elements horizontally in div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am fairly new to HTML and CSS and am trying to align the navigation elements for my slideshow horizontally in a div. I have tried the solutions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063325/align-html-elements-horizontally-in-a-div), but am not having any luck with my issue. With my current code, the circle elements are not center aligned with the < > arrows on either side. I think this is a simple fix, I'm just not sure where I'm going wrong in my code. Any help/explanations would be much appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .slideshow-container {
      position: relative;
      background: #f1f1f1f1;
    }

    .mySlides {
      display: none;
      padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* Next & previous buttons */
    .prev, .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      width: auto;
      color: #888;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      user-select: none;
    }

    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    .next {
      right: 0;
    }

    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
      background-color: #717171;
    }

    .dot-container {
      text-align: center;
      background: #ddd;
    }

    .dot {
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    }

    .active, .dot:hover {
      background-color: #717171;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides">
      <h1>Title 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <h1>Title 2</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <h1>Title 3</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot-container">
    <span class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    <span class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</span>
  </div>

  <script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
      }    
      if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
      }
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I horizontally center an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-can-i-horizontally-center-an-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox to align the items vertically in combination with line-height (set this the same as the height of the dots) and padding on the container (optional, to make it look nicer).

```css
.dot-container {
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    color: #888;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    user-select: none;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can vertical align with flex box for example.
This two classes i change:

```css
    .dot-container {
      height:40px;
      background: #ddd;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;      
    }

    .dot {
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    }
```

```js
  var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
  }

  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1;
    }    
    if (n < 1) {
      slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  }
```

```css
    .slideshow-container {
      position: relative;
      background: #f1f1f1f1;
    }

    .mySlides {
      display: none;
      padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* Next & previous buttons */
    .prev, .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      width: auto;
      color: #888;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      user-select: none;
    }

    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    .next {
      right: 0;
    }

    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
      background-color: #717171;
    }

    .dot-container {
      height:40px;
      background: #ddd;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;      
    }

    .dot {
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    }

    .active, .dot:hover {
      background-color: #717171;
    }
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h1>Title 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dot-container">
  <span class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</span>
</div>
```